# Controling the Order of Procedures in Netlogo

Tags: procedure, netlogo

`min-one-of` is reporting an error which I do not understand.  I understand that `min-one-of` requires a reporter procedure.  I have this, which is noted as `reporter-procedure` below.

However my reporter procedures takes as its input the output of another procedure.  My intention is that the output of `other-procedure` will be fed into `reporter-procedure` as its input.

Netlogo is telling me that this other procedure, `other-procedure` in the code section below, is expected to be a reporter.  Why?

Note that `other-procedure` takes four variables as inputs.

```
let best-taxi min-one-of available-taxis [reporter-procedure ( other-procedure var1 var2 var3 var4) ]
```

Now if I try this without parentheses, the error message is that `reporter-procedure` expected 1 input:

```
let best-taxi min-one-of available-taxis [reporter-procedure other-procedure var1 var2 var3 var4]
```

So I am guessing `reporter-procedure` executes first.  If so, why doesn't the first set of code (the code with parentheses) work by making `other-procedure` execute first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error doesn't actually have anything to do with with `min-one-of`.

> My intention is that the output of `other-procedure` will be fed into `reporter-procedure` as its input.

Only reporters have output. For `other-procedure` to have output that's fed into `reporter-procedure`, `other-procedure` must be a reporter.

You probably just need to declare `other-procedure` with `to-report` instead of `to` and make sure there's a `report` at the end of it with the output.